# Error in counting the number of times a character appears in a file in Case insensitive manner

Tags: c, file-io, char, scanf, fgetc

Please tell me what is wrong with below code. After executing it is showing

> "test.txt has 0 instances of letter 'r'"

```
`#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>
int main()
{
  FILE *fp;
  char ch,cmp;
  char f[100];
  int count=0,tu1,tu2;
  printf("Enter the file name\n");
  scanf("%s",f);
  fp=fopen(f,"r");
  printf("Enter the character to be counted\n");
  scanf("%c",&ch);
  tu1=toupper((int)ch);
  while((cmp=fgetc(fp))!=EOF)
  {
    tu2=toupper((int)cmp);
    if(tu1==tu2)
    {
      count++;
    }
  }
  fclose(fp);
  printf("\nFile \'%s\' has %d instances of letter \'%c\'",f,count,ch);
  return 0;
}`
```

Comment: What's your input? What's the contents of the file? Try adding a space before `%c` in `scanf("%c",&ch);`

Answer (score 2):

**Point 1**

Always check for the sucess of `fopen()` before using teh returned file pointer. Add a NULL check for `fp` after this (below) line of code. If NULL, discontinue the program

```
 fp=fopen(f,"r");
```

**Point 2**

Change

```
scanf("%c",&ch);
```

to

```
scanf(" %c",&ch); // mind the ' ' before c
```

to avoid the trailing newline (`\n`) stored by previous ENTER key press.

**Point 3**

As per the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgetc) of `fgetc()`, the return type is `int`. Change the data type of `cmp` from `char` to `int`.

Note:

1. The recommended signature of `main()` is `int main(void)`
2. It is always a good practive to initlize the local variables.